# R - ODBC to IBM DB2/AS400 connection blanks if .Rprofile loads without error

Tags: r, db2, rodbc

We recently got a load of trouble with our ODBC-connection to DB2/AS400 when we installed the gdata-package. After that we have done a nuke of all R-related files and started over but we still have a problem with the IBM DB2 connection. If the .Rprofile loads without error our DBS-odbc connection blanks (works fine outside of R). If I write something in the .Rprofile that leads to an error the ODBC-connection to DB2/AS400 works fine in both DBI/odbc and the older RODBC. DB2/AS400 has underlying CCSID = 278.

EDIT: I can establish the connection, but the object appears empty. For DBI I have added the CCSID = 1252 and gotten it to work. But no such luck yet for RODBC (that we're still using even if we plan to leave it)

What in the initializing process might go wrong that it only works when I insert an error in the .Rprofile? And how can I specify encoding in RODBC so that it works?

EDIT2: The problems are in R, since the ODBC-connection works in all other domains

**DBI/odbc - do work:**

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
con3 <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "mydb", uid= "myuser", pwd = "mypwd", 
                  CCSID = 1252)
```

**Rodbc - don't work:**

```
con3 <- odbcConnect(dsn=mydb,uid= myuser,mypwd,
                        DBMSencoding = "1252")
```

**Session-info:**

```
version 4.2.0 Patched (2022-05-12 r82348 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Finland.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Finland.1252    LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Finland.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=Swedish_Finland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] odbc_1.3.3 DBI_1.1.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.4       compiler_4.2.0  ellipsis_0.3.2  cli_3.4.1       hms_1.1.2       tools_4.2.0    
 [7] Rcpp_1.0.9      bit64_4.0.5     vctrs_0.4.2     blob_1.2.3      lifecycle_1.0.3 pkgconfig_2.0.3
[13] rlang_1.0.6
```

Comment: Which odbc driver (for i access) are you using, and what is its exact version?

Comment: @mao: An older version, iSeries Access ODBC Driver 13.00.01.00, we have had a ton of problems trying to update those. So at the moment it seems easier to try to handle it on the R-side.

Comment: In your position, I would get a "new" environment (i.e. not an upgrade) on which to install the __current__ i access odbc driver,  prove odbc is working standalone, then add the R components and see if you can get R working with a *current* baseline.  At least you would then know whether or not there is a known good working configuration at current levels.  Trying to get support for downlevel versions just wastes more time.

Comment: Meanwhile at your current downlevel versions, you might want to compare and analyse the odbc traces between the "working" and the "failing" situations, as sometimes this can yield results

Comment: ODBC works fine stand-alone, I can use it in Excel, Surveyor or other database tools. It's in R that it fails . And it works for DBI/ODBC just fine with ccsid specified, RODBC works if I add any statement that will lead to an error to the end of my .Rprofile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for DBI/odbc is to set the CCSID = 1252 and for RODBC to set Sys.setenv(NLS_LANG="LATIN1")

It makes the .Rprofile loading very slow but it works so there's that atleast.